# XML full path parsing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, getelementsbytagname

I'm sorry I don't even know the proper names of what I need. I apologize for that.

In PowerShell, I can do the following to specify what data I want to extract from XML:

```bsh
$participantID in $getParticipantListResponseXml.RESPONSE_TRANS_CONF.ACTION.GET.CONFERENCE.ONGOING_PARTY_LIST.ONGOING_PARTY.PARTY.ID
```

I can't just do in JavaScript:

```js
getElementsByTagName('ID')
```

Because 'ID'comes up in more than one place, and I need to specify the exact path. How could I do that?

Comment: What DOM library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This could help

```
document.evaluate( expression, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```

Example

```
document.evaluate( '//p', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
```